# highlightClass input of ngb-highlight selector does not work

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ngb-highlight selector to highlight some terms included in a table. Now, I want to add a background color and, following the online documentation, I used the highlightClass input and defined a custom class containing this new property.

Using its default class, it works changing font weight. The new class does not work.

employee-list.component.html

```html
<tr *ngFor="let employee of employees$ | async; index as i">
          <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
          <td>
            <ngb-highlight [result]="employee.firstname" [term]="filter.value" [highlightClass]="'employee-highlight'"></ngb-highlight>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ngb-highlight [result]="employee.lastname" [term]="filter.value" [highlightClass]="'employee-highlight'"></ngb-highlight>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ngb-highlight [result]="employee.email" [term]="filter.value" [highlightClass]="'employee-highlight'"></ngb-highlight>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ngb-highlight [result]="employee.role.name" [term]="filter.value" [highlightClass]="'employee-highlight'"></ngb-highlight>
          </td>
</tr>
```

employee-list.component.scss

```css
.employee-highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I expect a yellow background color, but the style does not change. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like ViewEncapsulation is not set to none in component

```
@Component({
....
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change

```
[highlightClass]="'employee-highlight'" to class="employee-highlight".
```

If this doesn't help please give me a link to your code over Stackblitz, I will check the code.

Comment: I changed to class and it highlights the entire word every time and not only the term specified. I solved defining employee-highlight like a global style into styles.scss file. Now highlightClass works!

Answer (score 0):

I solved defining employee-highlight like a global style into styles.scss file.